# gerrit ssh login issue

Tags: ssh, gerrit, hardlink

I am having an issue with my ssh login to gerrit.  When I use one key file it works, but with the other it does not.

```
ssh gerrit_admin@<host> -p 29418 -i ~/.ssh/project/prod_rsa
****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****
.....
ssh gerrit_admin@<host> -p 29418 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Now the issue seems obvious that one key is on the server and one is not.  However both of these key files are identical.  Not just copies, but a hard link meaning they both point to the exact same blocks on disk.

```
ls -il ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/project/prod_rsa 
7603695 -rw------- 2 nellis nellis 1693 Jun 23 13:22 /home/nellis/.ssh/id_rsa
7603695 -rw------- 2 nellis nellis 1693 Jun 23 13:22 /home/nellis/.ssh/project/prod_rsa
```

Why do these "two" keys which are very much the same produce different reseults?

Comment: That's just the private key, one half of the private/public key pair.  The public key is expected to be in a file with the same name and ending with .pub  Did you create a symlink for the public key as well?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, I don't have a public key for either file locally; it is on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what the problem here was, but I ended up just ditching the keys and importing new ones via the web interface.